# How to use Authenticated request with the Sitecore RESTful API

Tags: sitecore-api, webapi, authentication, post

As explained in the official Sitecore documentation, I'm using the following block of code to login into the Sitecore.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        /*context.log('ReadyState='+this.readyState);
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        context.log('Response='+this.responseText);
        }*/

};

xhr.open("POST", "https://content-XXXXX.com/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send('{"domain":"sitecore","username":"XXXXX","password":"XXXXXX"}');

    context.done();
};
```

The request sends back a token to inform the authentication succeeded, but the documentation does not explain how to use it to send another POST request, for example to creating an item in the content tree.
How should I use it ?

```
xhr2.open("POST", "https://content-XXXXXXXXX/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome",true);
xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); <-- TOKEN HERE ?
xhr2.send('{"ItemName": "MyTest","TemplateID":"XXXXXXXXX","Title":"Sitecore","Text":"MyTestText"}');
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: have you tried adding "token" header and the value?

Comment: Yes i tried by adding this line : xhr2.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + json['token']); where token is the token i got back after login

Comment: what about xhr2.setRequestHeader('token', json['token']);

Comment: Aren't you missing api keys ?? See https://iamlearningsitecore.wordpress.com/2018/06/01/setting-up-odata-item-api-for-item-service-in-sitecore/

Comment: @josedbaez. It worked like this, thank you !

Comment: Will add an answer with it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the token (received in the first request) in the header like:

```
xhr2.setRequestHeader('token', val);
```